# Tomcat: redirect `domain.com` to `www.domain.com`

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7, tomcat8

I hv my spring app pon tomcat. How can i redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com` in Tomcat. I checked `UrlRewriteFilter` but it seems a bit complicated to me as it was not happening. any othet solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [HttpRedirectFilter](http://www.zlatkovic.com/httpredirectfilter.en.html).

> HttpRedirectFilter is a servlet which implements javax.servlet.Filter interface. It inspects the URL of a HTTP request and either forwards the request to a different location, or redirects the user agent to a new URL. It can be used as a general redirector on a servlet container such as Apache Tomcat.

Comment: i user `urlrewrite` annd it solved it  tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to just add an A record to your DNS that points www.example.com to the same address as example.com.  How you go about that depends on your registrar or host.

Comment: no i dont think it is like that cos `www.example.com` `example.com` both are pointing to the same ip and its working also the matter is sharing same session between both

Answer (score 0):

You should write a servlet to redirect your request from example.com to www.example.com using Servlet Filters.

Try this out-

```
      HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;  
      HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        if (req.getServerName().equals("example.com")) {
            res.sendRedirect("http://www.example.com"+req.getRequestURI()); 
        }else{
            fc.doFilter(request, response);
        }
```